# FB Login issue due to old Android SDK of an app which doesn't exist anymore

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-login

FB Login feature of my web app has stopped working. Data Use Checkup is completed and I get this message when I access Facebook developer portal :

> You don't have any required action items to display. If any of your apps need immediate attention in the future, an item will show here.

However, users gets the following error when they try to login using FB:

> Facebook Login is currently unavailable for this app, since we are updating additional details for this app. Please try again later.

The only thing that might've caused this issue is the following warning:

> Your Facebook SDK is out-of-date. Please upgrade to v5.0 for access to new privacy features.

Which is related to an android app that we had before but, it's deprecated an no longer in google play store so basically I can't upgrade it since it doesn't exists anymore.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "google store". Facebook SDK is available in Maven Central repository: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.facebook.android/facebook-android-sdk (all versions from 2014 to now). Also make sure to read the documentation: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/

Comment: Thanks @Robert. I meant Google Play Store. Basically I removed the android app from Google Play Store which means that no one can use it. But somehow it's still connected to FB login and it's causing issue for the web application

Comment: usually you have to register apps that make use of and SDK like the one from Facebook somewhere at Facebook. Have you tried to unregister your app there?

Comment: That's what I have been looking for and unfortunately can't find it.

Comment: Have you checked the registration page if it allows to manage existing apps? https://developers.facebook.com/async/registration

Comment: I can see the app, but there is no option to unregister the Android integration. I tried to create a new app and integrate it with Auth0, but now Auth0 started duplicating accounts because the app id has changed.

Comment: Not sure if this is what you need to do, but In Meta For Developers, select your app and go to Settings > Basic. Scroll down to the Android integration and click the "X" icon. Save Changes.